# React + Meteor: basic dumb component returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm experimenting with meteor 1.5 and react 15.6.1.

/client/main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import App from '../imports/app';


Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

This is the App component:

```
//imports/app.js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Message from './message'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <Message message="Hello Cowboys" />
    )
  }
}
```

And this is my Message dumb component:

```
// /imports/message.js

import React from 'react';

const Message = (props) =>
  <p>{this.props.message}</p>;


export default Message;
```

The Error I receive is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined.`

Do you have any Idea why i am receiving this error ?

Comment: `this.props.message` should be `props.message` since you are using a stateless component and getting `props` as a parameter.

Comment: @bennygenel Ahhhh. Thank you! I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stateless component you should do this :

```
import React from 'react';

const Message = (props) =>
  <p>{props.message}</p>;

export default Message;
```